# How to get current scroll position of element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get current position of the scrollbar inside of `div` element, but the problem is cus when I get element: `div.scrollTop` value is always: `0`

This is React application, and in the parent component, I have a method which is passed down in child component:

```
 handleScrollPosition = (collectionId) => {
   const el = document.getElementById(collectionId);
   this.scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || el.scrollTop;    // this el.scrollTop is always 0 ? :( 
   this.scrolledCollectionId = collectionId;
 };
```

This method is called in child component on next `div`:

```
<div
   className="collection-body"
   id={this.props.id}
   onScroll={() => {
     this.props.handleScrollPosition(this.props.id);
   }}
>
```

What I am doing here is:

1. I am taking the element id
2. Get that element by id in a parent comp
3. Try to get current position of `scrollTop`
4. And save the current positon inside of variable `this.scrollTop`
5. And later want to scroll into that saved position

   But Problem is cus I cannot get and then save the correctly current position

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) "When an element's content does not generate a vertical scrollbar, then its scrollTop value is 0." So, does your child element have a scroll bar?

Comment: Maybe, you mean that I am trying to get scrollTop value from the wrong element? 
It makes sense...

Comment: Probably `window.pageYOffset` is not needed, simply write `this.scrollTop = el.scrollTop;`

Comment: @JamesDelaney maybe :D I'm not sure myself. If you take the scrollTop value from the parent element, that will tell you how far the scroll bar of the parent has moved. What do you mean by the scroll position of the child element? For example, do you mean how far is it from scrolling out of view?

Comment: @MattEllen Hey, I succed to get scrollTop by `offsetTop`. but the problem is when I set the scrollTop value: `el.scrollTop = scrollTop;`  el.scrollTop is still `0`. Do you know why?

Comment: If `el` is still the child element, does it have a scroll bar? If it does not, setting scrollTop will not do anything. Setting scrollTop changes the position of the scroll bar.

Comment: I believe it should have a scroll bar. Cus I am getting from that element offsetTop? 
And on parent element, I am not getting the offsetTop or scollBarTopl...

Comment: [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) "is the number of pixels from the top of the closest relatively positioned parent element". It has nothing to do with scroll bars.

Comment: You'll know if an element has a scroll bar if you can see a scroll bar when it renders on screen.